# CI4 - Trying to move image but get error "could not move file php6WkH2s to /var/www/example.com/development.example.com/app_dir/public/ ()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am trying to upload a file and move it to public/ folder.  The file uploads without problem to writable folder, however, it is the moving to the public folder that has a problem.

Here is my code;

```
$update_post->move(ROOTPATH.'public/', $update_post.'.'.$fileType);
```

Path is correct.  When I echo out `echo ROOTPATH.'public/';`  and then manually copy/paste, I do get to the destination directory.

Permissions correct.  There are my permission on the public/ directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 30 01:08 public
```

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the permissions of the folder within the public folder? That may be the issue.

Comment: The file is being saved in /public. I am not saving to any dir inside of public.  The permissions set on /public is what governs D R W X etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Reason:

It's because the [`move(string $targetPath, ?string $name = null, bool $overwrite = false)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/feea6c2688aa883cbe93060ebe2f58103cb4547d/system/Files/File.php#L132) method's  `$name` argument is invalid.

> $update_post->move( ... , $update_post.'.'.$fileType);

###### Explanation:

Concatenating an `class CodeIgniter\Files\File extends SplFileInfo` instance calls the inherited [`SplFileInfo` class's `__toString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.tostring.php) method which returns the path to the file as a string.

Note that it doesn't return the filename, which is what you're interested in.

##### Solution:

You should instead pass in the basename instead.

```php
$update_post->move(
    ROOTPATH . 'public/',
    $update_post->getBasename()
);
```

Alternatively, since you're *not* [changing the destination filename](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/files.html#moving-files), it's cleaner to just not pass in the second parameter of the `move(...)` method. I.e:

```php
$update_post->move(
    ROOTPATH . 'public'
);
```

##### Addendum:

If you wish to change the destination filename to a new name, try this instead:

[guessExtension()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/files.html#:%7E:text=Attempts%20to%20determine%20the%20file%20extension%20based%20on%20the%20trusted)

> Attempts to determine the file extension based on the trusted
> `getMimeType()` method. If the mime type is unknown, will return null.
> This is often a more trusted source than simply using the extension
> provided by the filename. Uses the values in **app/Config/Mimes.php** to
> determine extension:

```php
$newFileName = "site_logo"; // New filename without suffixing it with a file extension.
$fileExtension = $update_post->guessExtension();

$update_post->move(
    ROOTPATH . 'public',
    $newFileName . (empty($fileExtension) ? '' : '.' . $fileExtension)
);
```

##### Notes:

The `move(...)` method returns a new File instance for the relocated file, so you must capture the result if the resulting location is needed: `$newRelocatedFileInstance = $update_post->move(...);`

Comment: If you're still interested in getting the filename without the file extension, you could do it this way: `rtrim($update_post->getBasename(), "." . $update_post->getExtension())`

Comment: Many thanks.   I am actually trying to change the filename, too, to site_logo.mime.  I am not sure when to change the name.  getBasename() shows: $update_post->getBasename() string (9) "phpmMOVPu". I am now able to move the file.  At what point would I rename?

Comment: @spreaderman It's possible to change the destination filename. Please, check my edited answer in the **Addendum** section for further details.

Comment: I am asking another question so I will make a different port.  You helped me solve how to upload.  Many thanks!